# How to copy / clone entire Google App Engine Project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I was wondering if there is any way to clone a google app engine project. I could not find any help regarding this, though its quite often one may need this feature. Suppose I started developing an app engine application with so many options / apis configured. Now it would become my staging project and I want a separate project for production. Its never very easy to setup a separate production project with same settings and configurations.

Primarily I would like to make a copy of my staging project for production and make any required changes there.

Answer (score 2):

I had my app code in a git repo, in the `master` branch, from where I used to deploy to a to `my_app` GAE project. Just as you do I wanted a staging environment.

So I create a new `my_app-dev` GAE project, which would be the staging environment, with deployments exclusively from the `master` branch.

Then I pulled a `production` branch from the `master` branch (effectively a git-controlled copy of the app code) which I now use as the exclusive deployment source for the `my_app` (production) GAE project.

To reduce the risk of deploying to the wrong app I decided to only deploy by copy-pasting pre-cooked cmds from a `cmds` text file (added to the git repo) in the project dir with the complete commands to deploy the code to the appropriate GAE app. I created this file in the `master` branch, looking like this (I'm using the GAE SDK, not the gcloud one) this:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py update main/main.yaml apartci/apartci.yaml buildin/buildin.yaml
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py update_dispatch .
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py update_indexes -A my_app-dev main
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py update_cron -A my_app-dev .
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py update_queues -A my_app-dev .
```

I then merged the file in the `production` branch and updated it for the production GAE app (and added the git cmds to merge `master` branch changes verified in the staging environment into production):

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py update main/main.yaml apartci/apartci.yaml buildin/buildin.yaml
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py update_dispatch .
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py update_indexes -A my_app main
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py update_cron -A my_app .
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py update_queues -A my_app .

### merge into production:

git checkout master; git pull; git checkout production; git merge master

### check deltas between master and production:

git diff master..production
```

So now I have 2 side-by-side directories for the 2 environments: `my_app-staging` and `my_app-production`, containing git workspaces pulled from the `master` and `production` branches respectively. I work in `my_app-staging` until I'm happy with the results, then I switch to `my_app-production` and copy-paste the cmds to merge the changes and deploy into production.

At any moment I can check the deltas between the staging and the production branches in `my_app-production` (most likely there will be others beside just the GAE app name):

```
git diff master..production
```

**Update**

On the actual GAE app side I'm not aware of a cloning capability. I cloned my app manually, very early in the development process when there weren't many configs. The need for most config additions/changes came afterwards and I always applied them to both apps.

It *might* be possible to create such utility using the [Google App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/). But I didn't use it yet, I don't know if it covers all knobs for a complete cloning process.

Comment: Thats cool but it would have been a great advantage if there is a way to make a copy of project on google cloud platform itself. This is because a project can have many configurations (you enabled different api's like Gmail, Cloud data store etc). One will definitely not remember all of these configurations when having a separate deployment. In that case you will need to manually have to make all those configurations in your new project.

Comment: I totally didn't get this aspect. Yes, I agree with you. Answer updated.