# Create a new GCP project from existing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a Project on GCP. It has a postgres database, a node Appengine web app, and some other stuff. Now I am developing the app, and when everything is set up and running nicely I'd like to clone this project somehow and create a staging and a production environment/project.
So my project now is called `dev-awesomeapp`. Can I somehow make a `staging-awesomeapp` for staging and a `awesomeapp` for production from my existing `dev-awesomeapp`?

Edit: there is [an other question from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165490/how-to-copy-clone-entire-google-app-engine-project) that asks the same thing, but maybe it's possible now after 2,5 years?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy / clone entire Google App Engine Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165490/how-to-copy-clone-entire-google-app-engine-project)

Comment: It's the same question from 2017 and it says there is no way to clone a project. Maybe there is a way to clone a project now in (almost) 2020?

Comment: Maybe something like Hashicorp Terraform. Or run all your stuff in Kubernetes and write Helm charts.

Comment: Consider looking at Terraformer ... https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer ... which will generate Terraform (IaC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, but if you don't want to configure everything form the beginning each time, you can use "architecture as code" with tools like [deployment manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/) or Terraform.

This could help you in replicating your infrastructure, moreover it can be really helpful in automating any architectural changes if you use it in a CI/CD pipeline, making your release phase quicker and more reliable :)